# Blender cycles render appearing smaller than viewport view

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Images appear to be shrunk in rendered view.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you upload the file without the textures packed into the file, then anyone downloading it won't see the shrinking effect, because the object is not displaced without texture. But it's like @Nand27 says in the answer, try adjusting the _Midlevel_ setting in the _Displacement_ node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by displacement since your using displacement texture.
try adjust mid-level in the displacement node to .29

Comment: oh lol didn't realise that kept playing around with my subdivision modifier